# How can i unit test command line arguments in main

Tags: python, unit-testing

Hey I am trying to write unittest to test command line arguments in main. Argparser do not recognize arguments passed

```
def test_main_local_build(self):
    args = ['python', 'main.py','-b','test', '-d', '-S', '-m', 'el', '-l',
    'Network']
    main.main(args[1:])
```

Comment: Mock/patch `sys.argv`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please show us the (presumably separate) file that contains the class main? And maybe a little more on your motivation for testing main?

Comment: Sorry i would be happy to show all the code but not allowed. If you could give any basic idea. Thank you